# Enable thumbnail preview when uploading files in Google Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: nautilus, firefox, google-chrome

I have google chrome and when I upload photos to Facebook or Imageshack I cannot find a way to show thumbnails, only detail view. I also tried this in Firefox. This is quite important as it is stopping my friend from switching to Ubuntu over Windows.

Included a picture of the File Upload window, how do I  change this to a thumbnail view rather than the current list?

[image]

Comment: At present, I do not believe there is a way to switch to thumbnail view, only to click a file and get a thumbnail preview.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the cursor on to a file and you will see the thumbnail.

[image]

Comment: This does not address the question of how to switch to thumbnail view (which may not be possible), only of how to get individual previews of files.