# How to enlarge icons in browse menu?

Tags: icons, menu, resize

How can i enlarge icon in browse menu? When i want to upload some pictures to sites, and when a window opens for finding and selection images, icons are to small, i need to enlarge them so i can see pictures right away (dont want to click on every one to see preview). See image attached.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing from 'List' to 'Icons' in the 'View' menu?

Comment: didika, it appears the file upload window is a product of the browser and there is no way to change the thumbnail size, but only to click on it and get a preview. I'm still searching to see if it's possible to work around. I have deleted my answer which addressed the wrong issue in the meantime.

Comment: There is also another question on Askubuntu at http://askubuntu.com/questions/97325/enable-thumbnail-preview-when-uploading-files-in-google-chrome-firefox that somewhat asks the same question.